# Show that $f(x,y)=xy^2+x+y+1$ is differentiable at $(1,-1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I found that the derivative of $f$ is $l(x,y)=2x-y+2$.
Now I want to show that \begin{align*}
\lim_{||(h_1,h_2)||\rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(1+h_1,-1+h_2)-l(h_1,h_2)|}{||(h_1,h_2)||}=0
\end{align*}
By calculating, I have \begin{align*}
\lim_{||(h_1,h_2)||\rightarrow 0} \frac{|h_1h_2^2-2h_1h_2+h_2^2|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}=0
\end{align*}
Can you give some hint or solution about how I choose $\delta$ to show above limit?

Comment: A sum of 4 differentiable functions?

Comment: The usual way to take a derivative of a function $\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is to use the gradient: $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$. With respect to what is the derivative being taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can use following estimation:
$$\frac{|h_1h_2^2-2h_1h_2+h_2^2|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}} \leqslant\frac{|h_1h_2^2|+|2h_1h_2|+|h_2^2|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}} \leqslant   \\
\leqslant\frac{|h_1h_2^2|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}+ \frac{|2h_1h_2|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}+\frac{|h_2^2|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}\leqslant\\
\leqslant |h_2^2|+2|h_1|+|h_2|
$$